# Global hotkeys in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hotkeys

I've build a WPF application and want to add global hotkey support.
I want to be able to execute a method in my application from anywhere in windows, even when my application is minimized or running in tray. For example, execute the method with ctrl + alt + t.

Is this possible in WPF, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at RegisterHotKey in user32.dll. Here's a good example at pinvoke.net: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html

Comment: @user999999928 WPF doesn't natively support this.  It needs to be done through p/Invoke, which can be called from WPF.

Comment: Take a look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30568.wpf-implementing-global-hot-keys.aspx as well. I've found it really helpful.